# Cryptocurrency payment using Paytabs

Tags: payment

Currently I am doing analysis on [Paytabs](https://www.paytabs.com/en/) which is providing simple and trusted Payment Processing Solutions for Merchants or Individuals.

If I want to do the payments of bitcoins using Paytabs then how can we do that?

Answer (score 0):

PayTabs developer is here.

At the time being PayTabs doesn't support cryptocurrencies like BitCoin.